# How to stop - Google chrome window opening bottom right of screen

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

When I open a new Google Chrome window, the window itself opens at the bottom right of my screen. I should clarify that this happens after first window is open of chrome.

I have never used dual monitors on this laptop, and am running Windows 7.

I have tried re-sizing, windows adjustments to no avail.

The first window when opening chrome opens full size, however every subsequent window opens to the bottom right. Using CTRL+N to open new window

Window is not dragged open using Win7 snap controls. 
It is being dragged upwards by title bar and expanded by moving borders outwards.
Initially this works for the second and 3rd windows. However upon closing Chrome and re-opening I am presented with the same issue.

has any one been able to fix this issue. i have found nothing that works from Google's Dev sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exit Chrome, navigate to your [User Data folder](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory#TOC-Windows-7-or-Vista) (eg C:\Users\IanN\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default), then open the file `Preferences` and look for the following section

```
"browser": {
   .
   . <there will likely be a few sections here>
   .
   "window_placement": {
      "bottom": 1149,
      "left": 0,
      "maximized": false,
      "right": 1600,
      "top": 406,
      "work_area_bottom": 1149,
      "work_area_left": 0,
      "work_area_right": 1600,
      "work_area_top": 0
   },
   .
   .
   .
},…
```

Either adjust the number, or just delete the whole `window_placement` block—make sure to be careful not to delete other stuff; use the curly-braces as guides and make sure to match them. (Make a backup copy of the file, just in case.)

Now run Chrome. It should be displayed in the default location. If not, then you could delete the other `window_placement_*` blocks from `Preferences` and `…\User Data\Local State` (`Local State` is a file in the parent folder of `Default`.)

Comment: I have never looked at that file, perfect. I had no "window_placement block in preferences file but did find it in the local state folder and adjusted. Works. Lets see if it holds state now.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Even if I delete the whole file it just comes right back.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that when you re-size the window that you do not allow the "snap" feature to do the re-size.  If the snap feature does the re-size then the window in question will not remember its last size when it is opened again.  Remember that the snap feature happens in Windows 7 when you push `WIN` + `ANY DIRECTIONAL KEY` or when you drag a window or edge of a window to one of the edges of your screen.

Comment: thanks typoking. I added further steps to my org question

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and all other suggestions found in the Google threads, to no avail...until I found that that there were other instances of Chrome still running when the only visible window was closed. Once all instances were killed, a new instance remembered its window settings as it should.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was one of the extensions that was causing the problem, I turned off all the Chrome extensions and then turned them on one at a time and then opened Chrome until I found the culprit (in my case it was the "Max Payback" extension which somehow uses what is called OpenResty). Now I turn this extension on only when I need it and then turn it back off.
I hope this is useful/helpful!

Answer (score -1):

Simply change the screen resolution and then change it back to the original. It fixes the problem.

Comment: Could please explain how would this solve the OP problem?